# How to fix "Struct" to include a UIButton when clicked to open url?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, struct

> Here is the code in the struct. I have added the "url" but not sure if added in the struct correctly in all (3) places. The goal is to add "URL" to the struct!

```
struct State{

var title: String
var detailText: String
var description: String
var image: UIImage
var document: String
var url: String

 init(titled: String, detailText: String, imageName: String,     description: String, document: String, url: String)
{
self.title = titled
self.detailText = detailText
self.description = description
self.image = UIImage(named: imageName) ?? UIImage(named:"default")!
self.document = document
self.url = url
  }
}
```

> Below is the code for the array that I am using for your review. Does it need to be changed? or is it ok the way I added the "url"? The goal here is to add "URL" to the array!

```
class SelectedState{
// variables
var name: String // Name of State.
var states: [State] // List of all States.

init(named: String,includeStates: [State]){
    name = named
    states = includeStates
}
class func getSelectedStates() -> [SelectedState]{
    return [self.Reciprocal(), self.Unilateral(), self.NoAgreement(), self.ConstitutionalCarry()]
}
// Mark: - Private Helper Methods.
private class func Reciprocal() -> SelectedState {
    // Add states that are reciprocal states.
    var states = [State]()

    states.append(State(titled: "Alabama", detailText: "Reciprocal State", imageName: "alabama", description: "some text here", document: "somePDF", **url**: "https://www.anything.com"

    states.append(State(titled: "Texas", detailText: "Reciprocal State", imageName: "texas", description: "some text here", document: "somePDF", **url:** "https://www.somethingelse.com"
```

> Here is the code for the detailVC that I would like to add a "`UIButton`".  The `UIButton`, I added the button from `main.storyboard` to the `DetailVC`.  The goal here is to add a button to open urls from the array when clicked:  I am not sure how to code this correctly after adding a `UIButton`?

```
class StateDetailViewController: UIViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var stateTitleTextLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stateDetailTextTitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var stateDescriptionTextView: UITextView!
@IBOutlet weak var openURL: UIButton!

var state: State?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    title = "Reciprocal Details"

    stateTitleTextLabel.text = state?.title
    stateDetailTextTitleLabel.text = state?.detailText
    stateDescriptionTextView.text = state?.description
 }
```

> Here is the code for the `UIViewController`. I am not sure if I need to add additional code to the `UIViewController` since I added a button to the DetailVC?

```
import SafariServices
import UIKit
class StatesTableViewController: UITableViewController {
// Mark: - Data Model
  var selectedStates: [SelectedState] =          SelectedState.getSelectedStates()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "Reciprocity Agreements"
}
// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return selectedStates.count
}
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
    return selectedStates[section].states.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "stateCell", for: indexPath) as! StatesTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    let selectedState = selectedStates[indexPath.section]
    let states = selectedState.states
    let state = states[indexPath.row]
    cell.state = state
    return cell
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    let selectedState = selectedStates[section]
    return selectedState.name
}

var youselectedState: State?

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let selectedState = selectedStates[indexPath.section]
    let state = selectedState.states[indexPath.row]
    youselectedState = state

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "AgreementDetails", sender: nil)
}
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "AgreementDetails"{
        let StateDetailVC = segue.destination as!   StateDetailViewController
        StateDetailVC.state = youselectedState
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: Elaborate please. Which array? Which button?

Comment: So you want to open the URL for the last object in the `states` array, correct?

Comment: In states array if you have 10 state then do you want to create 10 buttons in your view controller? Then when a button is tapped want to open appropriate url in browser?

Comment: Each item in the array has a url associated with it.  The array populates a UITableView where each cell has a state name from the array.  When a Cell is selected from the TableView it moves to a detail VC to view more information about the state.  On the detailVC, there are 2 labels, a textview, and a button.  The button is what the user is suppose to click to view the url for the state.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to getting the url's from the array to open when the button is clicked.  I implemented this:

`@IBAction func watchButtonTapped(_ sender: SAButton) {
        if let url = URL(string: self.state!.url) {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)`